# What would you call a person who is always confused?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

It struck me today what would be the word for confused people. One of my friends is always confused in her daily life, she just can't decide what to do. If I call her, saying "you're a confused person" then it sounds more general. I am just wondering is there any single word for these kind of people?

Comment: I have googled it but couldn't find anything :) i am sorry if this question falls under general reference category   :)

Comment: Don't use Google, use a dictionary to look up synonyms: abash, addle, amaze, astonish, baffle, becloud, bedevil, befuddle, bemuse, cloud, clutter, complicate, confound, darken, daze, demoralize, discomfit, discompose, disconcert, discountenance, disorient, distract, embarrass, faze, fluster, fog, frustrate, fuddle, involve, lead astray, mess up*, misinform, mislead, mortify, muddle, mystify, nonplus, obscure, perplex, perturb, puzzle, rattle, render uncertain, shame, stir up, stump, throw off, throw off balance, trouble, unhinge, unsettle, upset, worry...

Comment: @Hugo, onelook's reverse dictionary can be useful, too... on a lighter note what about *sempre-flabbergasted* or *perma-befuddled*?

Comment: Not being able to decide what to do is not, in and of itself, a sign of confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Clueless](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=clueless)*. It's difficult to come up with a much better definition that the description in your question, but this one fits:

> **clueless**, *adjective*. Unknowing; utterly bewildered by life and events.

(Not to be confused with the movie "*[Clueless](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/clueless/)*," whose protagonist actually was not. Clueless, that is...)

Comment: This answer showed up in the review tab as "low quality". Is there any way you can improve it from a single hyperlinked word?

Comment: Heh; I was in the middle of expanding my answer when I got into an extended phone conversation

Answer (score 6):

I think there is no big mystery here. True if you say

> You are confused.

That implies transitional state, a state that has a specific duration.
However, if you say

> You are easily confused.

The this is a characteristic and you can use it to describe someones character (as permanent as it gets).

Finally, a common word for a person who is having problems deciding is **indecisive**.

Comment: +1 for indecisive, specifically because the OP states that the friend "can't decide what to do."

Answer (score 3):

I would called such a person an *addlepate*. Merriam-Webster unhelpfully defines that as *one who is addle-pated*, which it then defines [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/addlepated) as someone who is mixed up or confused. *Addled* is shorter if you want an adjective.

This term is nicely archaic and not derogatory, so you can fairly safely use it of your friends.

Comment: but, isn't it still missing the requested sense of permanence?

Comment: @Unreason, Perhaps. _Addled_ is sometimes used as a semi-euphemism for _drunk_ but I think being _addlepated_ is as permanent a state of affairs as being _confused_, perhaps even more so.

Answer (score 2):

Someone who is confused because they are hesitant or unable to make a decision, given a set of options to select from, could be called *dithering*, *irresolute* or perhaps a *vacillator.* Of course, obtaining the options to select from may be a similarly difficult task for this person.

Answer (score 1):

A state of confusion and being unable to decide what to do are different, I think. If the primary characteristic that you're trying to label concerns making decisions, then I'd agree with Unreason, ***indecisive*** is probably appropriate. But I'm not sure people without specific medical conditions would realistically be permanently confused. Some people are more prone to confusion, or to being overwhelmed. Maybe ***detached***? Maybe ***disengaged***? Or perhaps ***aloof**?

Answer (score 1):

Addleminded or scatterbrained.